# NodeJS with MongoDB - Pushing project to Github

Tags: node.js, git, mongodb, github

I am fairly new to NodeJS and MongoDB, I started a new project with a MEAN stack with Webstorm. I have an empty base project and want to commit it to Github.

I have a directory called "data" for the MongoDB part of the project. Just setting this directory up with MongoDB loaded it up with 300mb of files. Is it safe to gitignore this data directory? Github doesnt like the large files.

Picture of the files MongoDB generated

[image]

Comment: what's this 300mb of files ? If it's an empty project. Generally, in my node projects, I just push a dump of my mongoDb database.

Comment: @ceadreak honestly, I have no clue what all these files are... its mostly .wt files, .lock, .turtle... ill post a pic

Comment: I think these files does not to be there... But in an external directory used for all your projects. How did you install mongoDb ?
Note : Don't push your node_modules directory to github.

Comment: @ceadreak I have a node_modules directory ignored, they were all installed via npm --save. I think I may have misinterpreted the mongoDB tutorial I was following.

Comment: OK, uninstall the mongodb module and reinstall it with npm globally with the `-g` option. It will do the trick

Comment: @ceadreak For more information on the files created for an "empty" MongoDB 3.2 deployment see: [Why is an empty MongoDB database so big?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37758988/1388319).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely ignore the mongodb data files.

Usually the data files are not included in the project structure. You only need those files on your development machine so you can run your app locally. Once you deploy the application into production, you'll connect to a different database which is likely to be an entirely separate machine or several if you are running multiple nodes in a replica set.

You can also add the node_modules directory to your `.gitignore` as you will generally install these as part of your deployment process.

Github provides some sample `.gitignore` files for various languages - you might find it useful to look at the [nodejs one](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Node.gitignore)

Comment: Exactly the one i was using :-) Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it safe to gitignore this data directory

`Yes it is`. It is also a `good practice` to gitignore such content because versioning it make no sense. Specially when mongo is running, some of those files are locked for exclusive access by mongod and fiddling around with it could corrupt your database.

You can version the compressed output of `mongodump` and it does not sound insane. You can use the `Git hooks` such as `pre-commit` and `post-commit` to trigger `mongodump` and then compress the backup and then version it.

There are also online services that allow you to automatically backup your mongodb instance, for example [`MongoDB Monitoring Service`](https://www.mongodb.com/post/10764757533/announcing-mongodb-monitoring-service-mms) and others that you can google.

I am working on a `Node.js` project and I use `MongoDB` along with `Neo4j` databases. I have recently raised an issue with [neo4j-shell-tools](https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools/issues/71) and I would like to be able to export graph structure of my `Neo4j` database and I could easily version that just so at the end of project I look back and see how the `Neo4j` database evolved from scratch to a fully-functional database. If I ever have to rollback to a previous Neo4j database structure then I download the versioned graph structure and restore it in an empty database.

Neither MongoDB's nor Neo4j's databases are in my workspace, they are in their default locations. I have the following .gitignore file in case you wanted to reuse it and include rules for data directory (just like I have done for node-modules)

```
# Specifies intentionally untracked files to ignore when using Git
# http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

node_modules/
platforms/
plugins/
hooks/
public/jquery
photos/


# Compiled source #
###################
*.com
*.class
*.dll
*.exe
*.o
*.so

# Packages #
############
*.7z
*.dmg
*.gz
*.iso
*.jar
*.rar
*.tar
*.zip

# Logs and databases #
######################
*.log
*.sql
*.sqlite

# OS generated files #
######################
.DS_Store
.DS_Store?
._*
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes
ehthumbs.db
Thumbs.db
```

I also decided not to version control `node_modules` and whether to do it or not is debatable.

Answer (score 0):

For your information, you can use the datapack with Github.

https://github.com/pricing

[image]

But the best solution is to store your data on Compose.io (free) or an another cloud provider...

Answer (score 0):

You should install the mongodb module globally with npm.

https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally