# Why is an empty MongoDB database so big?

Tags: mongodb

When I create a new mongoDB database instance with the command

```
mongod --dbpath db
```

where `db` is a folder I have made in the directory from which I call the command. After running this and checking the size of the directory, I see that is is over **300MB** in size - when there's no data in there.

What's going on here?

Thanks for any help!

---

**EDIT**

Thanks to the people talking about the pre-allocated size for `journal`.

Here is a listing of files/folders in the database directory, sorted by order (there is a little bit of data in the database by now, but its size is neglible here):

```
$du -ha | sort -n
4.0K    ./WiredTiger
4.0K    ./WiredTiger.lock
4.0K    ./WiredTiger.turtle
4.0K    ./WiredTigerLAS.wt
4.0K    ./mongod.lock
4.0K    ./storage.bson
8.0K    ./.DS_Store
8.0K    ./diagnostic.data/metrics.2016-06-10T11-07-50Z-00000
8.0K    ./diagnostic.data/metrics.interim
 16K    ./_mdb_catalog.wt
 16K    ./index-3-3697658674625742251.wt
 36K    ./collection-0-3697658674625742251.wt
 36K    ./index-1-3697658674625742251.wt
 36K    ./sizeStorer.wt
 44K    ./WiredTiger.wt
 60K    ./collection-2-3697658674625742251.wt
 72K    ./diagnostic.data/metrics.2016-06-10T10-19-31Z-00000
100M    ./journal/WiredTigerLog.0000000003
100M    ./journal/WiredTigerPreplog.0000000001
100M    ./journal/WiredTigerPreplog.0000000002
168K    ./diagnostic.data/metrics.2016-06-10T11-17-58Z-00000
256K    ./diagnostic.data
300M    ./journal
301M    .
```

As you can see, the journal directory is taking up almost all of the space.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598971, as `mongod` isn't being started with `--replSet` in this example. A directory listing would confirm, but ~300MB is the expected size for the preallocated files in the [`journal`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/journaling/) directory when starting up a new MongoDB 3.2 server using the WiredTiger storage engine. The journal file size limit is 100MB and I'd expect three files on startup.

Comment: I've added sizes of files to my question - I think this confirms your assumptions. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for adding the directory listing (fwiw, `du -ha` would show friendlier file sizes). This is indeed the expected pre-allocation for journal files with WiredTiger (default storage engine as at MongoDB 3.2).

Comment: Good tip, thanks. Changed the output.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Depending on your version of MongoDB and configured storage engine, several data and metadata files will be preallocated on startup. This is the expected behaviour: an "empty" deployment still results in housekeeping and diagnostic data.

Based on your directory listing, you are running MongoDB 3.2 which defaults to using the WiredTiger storage engine. WiredTiger allocates up to 100MB per journal file, so your new deployment has ~300MB of preallocated [journal files](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/journaling/):

```
     100M    ./journal/WiredTigerLog.0000000003
     100M    ./journal/WiredTigerPreplog.0000000001
     100M    ./journal/WiredTigerPreplog.0000000002
```

Aside from journal files, other metadata that will be created in your `dbpath` (without you having explicitly created databases yet) will include:

- A `local` database with a capped collection called [`startup_log`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/local-database/#local.startup_log) with some diagnostic information about each startup invocation of this instance of `mongod`. There will be an associated collection and index file for `local.startup_log`; the filenames are opaque but as the first files created I'm guessing in your example these might be:

  ```
   36K    ./collection-0-3697658674625742251.wt
   36K    ./index-1-3697658674625742251.wt
  ```
- Multiple WiredTiger metadata files. There will always be at least one database in a deployment since the `local` database is created by default for the `startup_log`:

  ```
  4.0K    ./WiredTiger
  4.0K    ./WiredTiger.lock
  4.0K    ./WiredTiger.turtle
  4.0K    ./WiredTigerLAS.wt
   16K    ./_mdb_catalog.wt
   36K    ./sizeStorer.wt
   44K    ./WiredTiger.wt
  ```
- A `diagnostic.data` directory; this is for periodic sampling of server status metrics:

  ```
  168K    ./diagnostic.data/metrics.2016-06-10T11-17-58Z-00000
  72K    ./diagnostic.data/metrics.2016-06-10T10-19-31Z-00000
  ```

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new database, MongoDB create space for the [oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/).

The oplog (operations log) is a special capped collection that keeps a rolling record of all operations that modify the data stored in your databases.

Comment: The oplog is specific to replication, so would not be created for this example of a standalone server (`mongod --dbpath ...`). There are other data files that may be preallocated depending on the MongoDB version and storage engine; a directory listing would provide more insight.